# General Gaussian distribution relation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, statistics

I'm trying to solve a question from Pathria's statistical mechanics textbook (10.21) but it is more math oriented.

Show that, for a general Gaussian distribution of variables $u_j$ , the average of the exponential of a linear combination of the variables obeys the relation:

$\left\langle \exp\left(\sum_j a_j u_j\right) \right\rangle=\exp\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\left\langle\left(\sum_j a_j u_j\right)^2 \right\rangle \right)$

I'm not entirely sure how to write this; I was doing Taylor series expansions of exponentials and I could solve it easily if it were a standard normal (mean=0).  I believe the linear combination of normal variables is normal, so this seems to have something to do with the log-normal distribution?

I don't need a full solution; just a hint to go forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full solution.

Since $\sum\limits_ja_ju_j$ is normal, you are asking to show that for every normal random variable $u$, $$\langle\mathrm e^u\rangle=\mathrm e^{\langle u\rangle^2/2}.$$ If $u$ is normal with mean $m$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then $u=m+\sigma v$ where $v$ is standard normal hence $$\langle\mathrm e^u\rangle=\mathrm e^m\cdot\varphi(\sigma),\qquad\varphi(t)=\langle\mathrm e^{tv}\rangle.$$ By definition, $$\varphi(t)=\int_\mathbb R\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm e^{tx}\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}\mathrm dx=\mathrm e^{t^2/2}\int_\mathbb R\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm e^{-(x-t)^2/2}\mathrm dx=\mathrm e^{t^2/2},$$ hence $$\langle\mathrm e^u\rangle=\mathrm e^m\cdot\mathrm e^{\sigma^2/2}.$$ On the other hand, $$\langle u\rangle^2=m^2+\sigma^2,$$ hence:

> The desired identity holds if and only if $\sum\limits_ja_j\langle u_j\rangle$ is $0$ or $2$.

The hypothesis that $\langle u_j\rangle=0$ for every $j$, which implies that $\sum\limits_ja_j\langle u_j\rangle=0$, is probably missing from the statement of the exercise.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your response.  But doesn't this implicitly assume that $e^u$ is normally distributed.  However, if $u$ is normally distributed, then isn't $e^u$ log-normally distributed?

Comment: "doesn't this implicitly assume that eu is normally distributed" No it does not. Absolutely not. Neither implicitely nor explicitely. Fortunately. What gave you the idea it did?

Comment: I'm just a little confused because the definition of expectation value is:
$\int \, xp(x) \, dx$ where $X$ has a probability distribution of $p$.  However, you have:
$\langle e^{tx} \rangle=\int \, \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{tx}e^{-x^2/2}$.  Doesn't this assume $e^{tx}$ has a standard normal distribution?

Comment: No. If $X$ has density $p$ then, for every (measurable and suitably integrable) function $g$, $$\langle g(X)\rangle=\int g(x)p(x)\mathrm dx.$$ Apply this to $g:x\mapsto\mathrm e^{tx}$.

Comment: Oh, I should have remembered this! Thanks you